# Cookies are being sent by Django but not received by frontend

Tags: javascript, reactjs, django, http, django-middleware

I'm attempting to send a cookie to the front end using django middleware. In the middleware I'm seeing that the cookie is getting created and then attached to the response.

But once I'm on the frontend (React) I'm not finding the cookies with .get('Set-Cookies') and can't figure out why.

Middleware (python)

```
class DeviceCookieMiddleware(object):
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        response = self.get_response(request)
        new_customer = None

        if 'device' not in request.COOKIES:
            new_customer = Customer.objects.create()

            response['Set-Cookie'] = f'device={new_customer.device}; Max-Age=3600; Secure; HttpOnly; SameSite=None'

        request.new_customer = new_customer
        print(response.headers)
        return response
```

Frontend (Javascript)

```
export async function fetchProductsBySlugs(slugs, setterFunc, startDate, endDate, dateChange) {
  const [start, end] = parseDates(startDate, endDate)

  try {
    const response = await fetch(`${SERVER_ADDRESS}/api/products/products/list/?slugs=${slugs.join(',')}&${datesUrlString(start,end,dateChange)}`);

    const cookies = response.headers.get('Set-Cookie')
    console.log(cookies)

    const products = await response.json();

    setterFunc(products);
    return products;
  } catch (error) {
    throw error;
  }
}
```

Things I've Tried:

- I've looked around and attempted reordering my middleware in Django settings as I've heard that can cause issues based on the order in which it's processed.
- I've also tried different browsers. Firefox clued me into the fact there was no SameSite setting and that could be the issue. But once I updated that, it still will not appear.
- I tried using the response.set_cookie() method from Response.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you.

Comment: HttpOnly cookies cannot be accessed by client side script.

Answer (score 0):

So I ended up figuring it out. I was not checking in the right place, the cookies were being set automatically by the browser. All I had to do was check the Application > Storage > Cookies in Chrome Dev Tools.

Apparently, as Himura pointed out, if the request is set to httpOnly you'll won't be able to access this cookie or header in Javascript. This is why I was unable to console.log the cookie in the fetch request.

Now to access the cookie I just search the document for cookies using this (found on django's docs)

```
export function getCookie(name){
    let cookieValue = null;
    if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== ''){
      const cookieList = document.cookie.split(';')
      for (let i = 0; i < cookieList.length; i++){
        const cookieItem = cookieList[i].trim()
        if (cookieItem.substring(0, name.length + 1) === (name + '=')){
          cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookieItem.substring(name.length + 1))
          break
        }
      }
    }
    return cookieValue
  }
```